# I have this code and I don't get why the result of print(su) isn't zero

Tags: python, decorator, coroutine, yield

Help me understand why `yield total` doesn't comes out as `0` at the first calling!

Since [sumer] passed though [primer] by @coroutine,
[su] already met next() in side of primer right?

So I'm guessing the result of `print('EX2-1 -',su)` 
should be
`0`

But the real result turns out to be just showing the address of su,
and only after `su.send(100)` the value comes out as 100

What am I missing??

```
from functools import wraps
from inspect import getgeneratorstate


def coroutine(func):
   @wraps(func) 
   def primer(*args, **kwargs):
       gen = func()
       next(gen)
       return gen
   return primer

@coroutine
def sumer():
    total = 0
    term = 0
    while True :
        term = yield total
        print('term recieved')
        total += term

su = sumer()
print('EX2-1 -',su)
print(getgeneratorstate(su))
print('EX2-1 -', su.send(100))
```

Comment: `su` is the generator object, not the value it yields.

Comment: Why do you assign `term` like this: `term = yield total`? `term` will always be `None` this way.

Comment: @alirezafnatica that's not true, term will take the value sent to the coroutine. Read e.g. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0342/

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yup! I didn't notice he is using `send()`, but if you try to call `next()` anytime after the first time, you will get an exception as `term` is None.

Comment: @WonjuneShin Well the `@coroutine` decorator that you use ensures that whenever you make an instance of your generator, the first `next()` is called on it and you don't need to do it manually, but for the subsequent calls, you have to do `next(su)` (of course it will cause an exception as I suggested above) or `su.send(100)` everytime you want the loop to continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's go through your code step by step.

The `coroutine` decorator is gonna return it's inner function which is `primer` and that's it... So after you apply `@coroutine` to the `sumer` , the  `sumer` label is now pointing to the `primer` function.

Next when you call the `primer` function in line `su = sumer()`, it will create a coroutine in line `gen = func()` then primes it with `next(gen)` and returns the *primed* coroutine.

Up until now `su` is pointing to whatever the `primer` function returned, which is a generator not the value !

Your problem is exactly here, if the `primer` returns `next(gen)` you will get `0`. But that `0` is just skipped and your coroutine is now ready to receive values.

Try to change it to:

```py
from functools import wraps

def coroutine(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def primer(*args, **kwargs):
        gen = func()
        return next(gen)

    return primer


@coroutine
def sumer():
    total = 0
    while True:
        term = yield total
        print('term recieved')
        total += term


su = sumer()
print('EX2-1 -', su)
```

It is `0` now but not useful anymore.
Since `su` is not the generator anymore, you can't pass it to the `getgeneratorstate` and also send value to it. It is an integer now.

Comment: Returns the generator not the value! I get it! Thank you so much! Good teacher you are :)

Answer (score 0):

`su` is the generator object itself. If you want to get the current value of `total` at any point you need to make it yield it, but you can't use `next()` because this will make `term` be `None` which will cause an error. Instead, you need to use `.send(0)`:

```py
from functools import wraps
from inspect import getgeneratorstate


def coroutine(func):
   @wraps(func) 
   def primer(*args, **kwargs):
       gen = func()
       next(gen)
       return gen
   return primer

@coroutine
def sumer():
    total = 0
    term = 0
    while True :
        term = yield total
        print('term recieved')
        total += term

su = sumer()
print('EX2-1 -', su.send(0))
print(getgeneratorstate(su))
print('EX2-1 -', su.send(100))
```